# Can the best constants in harmonic analysis be approximated in principle?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, na.numerical-analysis

Consider the trivial example of Holder's inequality $\|f\|_p\,\|g\|_q\geq |fg|_1$ if $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1, p,q\geq 1$ and $f,g$ are functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let's suppose we don't know how to show the inequality, we define $C>0$ to be the largest constant such that  $\|f\|_p\,\|g\|_q\geq C |fg|_1$ holds for all $f,g$. It is not hard to see that $C$ can be numerically approximated by choosing $f,g$ to be step functions supported on $[0,1]^n$ taking values in dyadic numbers. In this way we may, in principle numerically approximate $C$.

My question is what about more nontrivial examples? Have people tried to numerically approximate the best constants to some more advanced inequalities for harmonic analysis?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @mathworker21 would you mind elaborate on that? Maybe provide some references?

Comment: [e.g.](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0311452)

Comment: Isn't it what people do all the time over centuries?

Comment: @WlodAA what would be an example of this in more advanced more recent harmonic analysis? Have such things give any new conjectures?